# SML: Remove the entry from the List

Tags: list, sml

How can I delete the element `elem` in list `L`? If the list does not contain elem, then the function should return the list unchanged.

For instance:

```
L = [1, 3, 4, 0, 5, 7]    
elem = 5
```

So far I have the following function:

```
fun removeElem elem myList[] = myList
  | removeElem (myList::tl) = if mem myList elem then
                                rm elem myList[]
                              else
                                removeElem elem tl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn the question around and ask how to keep only those items not equal to `elem`. This fits cleanly with `filter`:

```
fun removeElem elem myList = filter (fn x => x <> elem) myList
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will accomplish what you want to do: remove the element (actually it will remove all instances of the element if there are more than one) and return the rest of the list as-is:

```
fun remove_element (list, element) =
    case list of
    [] => []
      | list_head::list_tail => let val a = remove_element(list_tail, element)
                       in
                           if list_head = element
                           then a
                           else list_head::a
                       end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun delete (s,[])     = []
  | delete (s,x::xs') = 
    if s = x then xs' (* more efficient than call delete function again *)
    else x::delete(s, xs')
```

Comment: This only removes the first occurrence of the element.

Comment: What if I want to remove a real element? What should I add to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
fun remove_element (elemlist, elem) = 
  case elemlist of
  [] => []
  | head::tail => if elem = head
                  then remove_element (tail, elem)
                  else head::remove_element (tail, elem)
```

Output SML/NJ:

```
val remove_element = fn : ''a list * ''a -> ''a list
val it = () : unit
(* matching *)
- remove_element ([1,2,3,4,5], 4);
val it = [1,2,3,5] : int list
(* non matching *)
- remove_element ([1,2,3,4,5], 7);
val it = [1,2,3,4,5] : int list
(* multiple instances *)
- remove_element ([1,3,4,4,5],4);
val it = [1,3,5] : int list
```

Answer (score 0):

With no libraries or extra functions

```
fun remv(L, c) = 
  if null(L) then nil
  else if c=hd(L) then remv(tl(L), c)
  else hd(L)::remv(tl(L), c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
fun remove_element (elemlist:int list, elem:int) = 
  case elemlist of
  [] => []
  | head::tail => if elem = head
                  then remove_element (tail, elem)
                  else head::remove_element (tail, elem)
```

Comment: Answering questions here is good but this answer appears to copy the code from Vikram's answer that was written over four years ago. New answers to old questions should show new information or give new insights into the topic. Repeating existing answers is just clutter.

Answer (score -2):

also you can use this function to remove duplicate entries from a list:

```
fun remove_duplicates(xs: ''a list) =
    let 
        fun helper(ds: ''a list, m: ''a) =
            if null ds 
            then []
            else if hd ds = m
            then helper(tl ds, m)
            else hd ds :: helper(tl ds, m)
    in 
        if null xs
        then []
        else hd xs :: remove_duplicates( helper(tl xs, hd xs) )
    end
```

Comment: I don't think this question is asking about removing duplicates, just a certain element.