# SML: function with multiple outputs

Tags: list, sml

I´m a newbie in SML and I´d like to update my function so that it has two outputs: a list AND 1 or 0. The function was proposed here: [SML: Remove the entry from the List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558700/sml-remove-the-entry-from-the-list). It returns an updated list without a row that contains ´elem´.

```
fun removeElem elem myList = filter (fn x => x <> elem) myList
```

The function should return a new list AND 1, if a raw has been deleted. Otherwise, it should return an old list AND 0.

Any hint or example is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No,it´s not a homework. I´m just learning SML. Therefore I don´t ask to write a complete function for me. I´d like to see an example of a similar function with multiple outputs. Thx.

Comment: Likely to be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206865/what-is-a-good-book-or-tutorial-on-standard-ml

Comment: @KlausosKlausos: that's basically what the `[homework]` tag here means, so you might want to use that in the future. It tells us that the objective is to learn, so we shouldn't give you a complete solution, but instead explain and hint and try to help you understand the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that *all* SML functions take a single input and return a single output. Instead, think of returning a tuple containing the new list and a flag indicating whether any elements were removed. One possibility is to use a couple of functions from the standard basis to test whether `elem` is in `myList` and build up a tuple consisting of that and the results from the `filter` shown in the question. The test might look like:

```
Option.isSome (List.find (fn x => x = elem) myList)
```

There are more concise ways to write that, but it shows the idea. Note that it returns a `bool` instead of an `int`; this is more precise, so I won't convert to the integers requested in the question.

A drawback of the above is that it requires traversing the list twice. To avoid that, consider the *type* that the function must return: a tuple of a list without `elem` and a flag showing whether any `elem`s have been removed. We can then write a function that take a new value and a (valid) tuple, and returns a valid tuple. One possibility:

```
fun update(x, (acc, flag)) = if x = elem then (acc, true) else (x :: acc, flag)
```

We can then apply `update` to each element of `myList` one-by-one. Since we want the order of the list to stay the same, apart from the removed elements, we should work through `myList` from right to left, accumulating the results into an initially empty list. The function `foldr` will do this directly:

```
foldr update ([], false) myList
```

However, there is a lot of logic hidden in the `foldr` higher-order function.

To use this as a learning exercise, I'd suggest using this problem to implement the function in a few ways:

- as a recursive function
- as a *tail-recursive* function
- using the higher order functions `foldl` and `foldr`

Understanding the differences between these versions will shed a lot of light on how SML works. For each version, *let the types guide you.*

Answer (score 4):

As has been stated in some of your previous questions; Returning 0 or 1 as an indicator for what happened is a really bad design, as you don't get any guarantees from the types, whether or not you will get -42 as the result. Since you are working with a strongly typed language, you might as well use this to your advantage:

1. The most obvious thing to do instead would be to return a boolean, as that is actually what you are emulating with 0 and 1. In this case you could return the pair `(true, modified_list)` or `(false, original_list)`.
2. Since you want to associate some data with the result, there is another -- perhaps, for some, less -- obvious thing to do; Return the result as an option, indication a change in the list as `SOME modified_list` and indication no change as `NONE`.

In either case you would have to "remember" whether or not you actually removed any elements from the original list, and thus you can't use the `filter` function. Instead you would have to do this for yourself using somewhat the same code as you originally posted.

One way would be like this

```
fun removeElem _ [] = (false, [])
  | removeElem elem (x::xs) =
    let
      val (b, xs') = removeElem elem xs
    in
      if elem = x then
        (true, xs')
      else
        (b, x::xs')
    end
```

Another way would be to use a accumulator parameter to store the resulting list

```
fun removeElem elem xs =
    let
      fun removeElem' [] true res = SOME (rev res)
        | removeElem' [] false _ = NONE
        | removeElem' (x::xs) b res =
          if elem = x then
            removeElem' xs true res
          else
            removeElem' xs b (x::res)
    in
      removeElem' xs false []
    end
```

Since the solution is being built in the reverse order, we reverse the result just before we return it. This makes sure that we *don't* have to use the costly append operation when adding elements to the result list: `res @ [x]`

Comment: I find the phrase "you can't build the resulting list with a non-tailrecursive [sic] function" to be unclear, even misleading. You can add an accumulating parameter to your `fooFilter` without making it tail recursive. I'm really not sure what you're getting at, perhaps you could clarify it?

Comment: I don't see how it is unclear, if you include the assumption as to why it is not possible: namely that he wants to return both the indicator *and* the list, as I also stated in the same sentence you quoted (but neglected to include). Adding the accum parameter would most definitely make `fooFilter` tail recursive (unless you deliberately add unneeded expression around the recursive call).

Comment: No, it does not follow that `fooFilter` would automatically become tail recursive. You could well imagine getting the result of a recursive call with the tail of the list, then building up a new result from that. This could have the same modified signature, would not have the call to `fooFilter` in tail position, and is only unreasonable in terms of stack space.

Comment: Hmm. Not quite sure if this is what you were getting at, but i fixed another (better) example that is still tail recursive without using the accumulator parameter.

Comment: The first version is exactly what I was getting at: the `if` occurs after the call to `removeElem`, so `removeElem` is not in tail position. Thanks for putting in the effort to clarify the point.